# PhpStorm and readonly entity

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

I'm trying to clear all warnings of my project, but I'm getting one warning:

> Property is only read but never written

```php
class Utilisateur extends AbstractEntity implements UserInterface, PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface
{
    #[ORM\Id, ORM\Column(type: "ULID", unique: true), ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "CUSTOM"), ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: UlidGenerator::class)]
    private readonly Ulid $id;

    #[Pure]
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->demandeTransports = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->propositionTransports = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->tchatDemande = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Ulid
     */
    public function getId(): Ulid
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
}
```

[image]

Does anyone have an idea how to clear this warning?

I don't want to add `setId()` cause, I never want to explicitly call `setId()` myself (`CustomIdGenerator` does that).

Comment: Just choose ignore (or suppress or similar wording) from the context menu. PhpStorm is just doing static analysis, and this is just a warning that in your case doesn’t apply.

Comment: I noticed that as well. Before PhpStorm didn't complain about it. I don't know if it coincides with the upgrade to Doctrine 2 or with the use of PHP Attributes. But it does tickle my OCD.

Comment: Since you already have a getter and the property is readonly you could change visibility from private to public. This will at least suppress the warning from PHPStorm.